# In Xamarin Studio Images are not getting moved to the root of the iOS app package

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a folder that I have created "Libraries/GKImagePicker" that has png files in them. Unlike XCode, these images do not get automatically copied to the root of the bundle for iOS apps. So I added the following to the .csproj file:

```
<IPhoneResourcePrefix>Resources;Libraries/GKImagePicker</IPhoneResourcePrefix>
```

I have also set the image files to:

```
Build Action -> BundleResource
and also tried...
Build Action -> Content
```

And, after cleaning and compiling, when I look at the structure in the simulator folders... and open the app package... I see the Libraries/GKImagePicker folders no matter what I do... so:

```
new UIImage("Libraries/GKImagePicker/image1.png") works
and
new UIImage("image1.png") doesn't work
```

Any help? I would like new UIImage("image1.png") to work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is the intended behavior.  If you set a file to "Content" it will get copied to your app bundle with it's full path.  If you want the file to be in the root of your bundle, put it in the root of your project.

Comment: So there is no way to "organize" my content into folders while having them all ultimately copied to the root of my bundle? I thought that is what the iPhoneResourcePrefix tag was for in the csproj... is there no way to do this?

Comment: I always includes images as Content - the behavior may be different if you use them as Resources.  There is a UIImage.FromResource() method that you might want to try.